# Display arabic font in web page which shown Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø³Ù in database

Tags: php, sql, arabic, arabic-support

I have arabic font `Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø³Ù`  in my db. It is fetching perfect arabic in some pages.

But it does not in another pages. why this differentiation?

I have put `<meta charset="utf-8">` in both pages.

Any other things need to take care?
Help me

**Edit**: Solved

Comment: Have you set the DB encoding as utf8? Have you set the DB handler as utf8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @chris85: where the db handler can shown?

Comment: I have Arabic displayed right in my Mysql database with PHPMyAdmin and displayed right in webpage. Provide more information about your database setup

Comment: Where you establish your database connection.

Comment: @YehiaSedky: If my database shown arabic like yours it will display as question mark in `admin/page2.php` ,and  `page1.php` will display perfectly. and vise versa...pls help me

Comment: @chris85:this is my database `collation` of table field `name`-   `varchar(100) utf8_general_ci`

Comment: That is not the database connection. Show your PHP code that makes the connection to the database (with credentials removed).

Comment: @condition0 show us your php code that inserts the data in your database and the code that retrieves it. A quick try is to insert query `SET NAMES 'utf8'` at the start of the connection and try to insert data again

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#quicklookup):

> The declaration should fit completely within the first 1024 bytes at
>   the start of the file, so it's best to put it immediately after the
>   opening head tag.

So it might be that you are placing the charset meta tag somewhere deep in your head, in a way that is does not appear in the first 1024 bytes loaded !

Try putting it **directly after the head opening tag** and see if that solves your problem !

Comment: Firstly thank for your nice answer...i will check it

Answer (score -1):

use this function

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

or

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

for pdo ,your connection string like

```
"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8"
```